# Find and Revoke User in GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

We have no of GCP projects (Ex: 50 projects) under an organization. We want to revoke one of the user access, but not sure what are all the projects he has the access. So we need to identify that user access list and then revoke the same.
As a 1st step I tried the following command to fetch user and roles details. But it gives all the users info. I couldn't find the parameter for the specific user.

gcloud projects get-iam-policy "project-id"

Can anyone help me in this scenario.

Comment: A project is a resource. Cloud Storage, KMS, App Engine, etc are resources as well. IAM policies are bound to resources. IAM policies can be inherited. Removing a user from all projects does not mean that all access for that identity is removed.

Comment: I believe, removing an user from IAM will restrict that user to access the resources under that project.

Comment: That is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: You mean we have to remove the user access from each resources.

Comment: If an IAM policy has been bound to a resource that grants the user (identity) permission, yes, you must also remove that policy. Your situation is a good example of why organizations should only use Google Workplace or Google Identity Platform for users, groups, etc. That way you can simply delete/disable the identity. If you are using Gmail user identities, you do not have that option. Note: if a user/identity is also part of a group that has permissions, you need to remove the user from the group.

Comment: I have added an user with basic viewer access and added additional role as storage object viewer.
Then I created a new storage bucket and verified that this user role has permission to that bucket as storage object viewer. Later I removed that user from IAM, and cross verified that, the same user is not reflected under storage permission. Which means if we remove the user from IAM, it removes all respective roles from each resource, so that the user can't access any of the resources in that project. I hope we need not to remove from each resource, IAM handles that internally.

Comment: You added a policy to the project and then removed it. You did not add a policy to the bucket or a bucket object. You did not test inherited rights (policies at the ORG and Folder level. You did not test groups. And no, IAM does not handle it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235323/discussion-between-mani-and-john-hanley).

Comment: My comments should point you in the direction you need to research first.

Comment: Yes you are right, If i add the user directly under the storage permissions its intact even though the user removed from IAM.
Thanks for your time and explanation for this understanding.
Is there any command to find the assigned roles/ policies against a user irrelevant of any resource
Is there any option to do that, if yes you small hint will help me a lot.

Comment: You can use Asset Inventory to search IAM to find the policy bindings. Be careful, all resource aren't scanned. https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

Comment: Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere this helps me for this scenario. I will check asset inventory comments and some inputs in this thread if possible.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for  your comments that made me to do some research on IAM part.

Answer (score 1):

As @John Hanley mentioned in comments, using Cloud Identity Platform can be the best workaround in this situation. Besides there are some other ways in [revoking access of the user](https://cloud.google.com/security/data-loss-prevention/revoking-user-access#revoking_access).

This following steps will be an efficient and secure way to revoke a user’s access:

1.In the Google Cloud Platform console, go to the IAM permissions page.

2.Select the project you want to remove an account from.

3.Click the checkbox next to the row containing the account you want removed from the member list, then click Remove. Alternatively, click the trash      can icon next to the account you want to remove.

This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security/data-loss-prevention/revoking-user-access) has detailed instructions of revoking a user account from GCP and to get the roles assigned to the user refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/viewing-users-and-permissions).